# BJT Emitter Degeneration Rπ

Tags: differential, input-impedance, common-emitter

I am a bit confused about this differential base-emitter resistance.

I has been said that r_pi doesn't have much influence on small signal input impedance, when CE with emitter degeneration is used. Well, I doubt this claim.

Can someone please explains why or when should r_pi be neglected in small signal input resistance calculus for CE with emitter degeneration?

[image]

Comment: The emitter resistor is NOT "most probably bypassed by capacitor" at all and this claim is putting me off answering because it seems you have things muddled up. I'm not sure what your question is based on your false claim.

Comment: @Andyaka But how? Capacitor to ground from emitter lead equals as grounded emitter for small signal analysis, right? Why else would emitter resistor be bypassed. And I didn't muddled up anything...

Comment: You say that "Emitter resistor will be most probably bypassed by capacitor" and this is just not true. Then you say "so emitter can't really have much influence on small signal input impedance" and this is also not true. Your claims and your questions are not obviously separated enough to make an answer. Clean up your question and don't make false assertions.

Comment: @Andyaka Edited.

Comment: The answer is simple: Write down the input resistance for all cases you are intersted in (with/without RE or CE). And then - as a second step - use real values and see if the base-emitter resistance plays a major role (lets say > 10%) or not.

Comment: @LvW I don't quite get what you mean..

Comment: When you have a sum of two quantities C=A+B and B is much smaller than A, the you can perhaps live with the error by letting C=A. In the world of electronics nothing is correct by 100% because we ALWAYS neglect some effects. But depending on the specific application and the allwowed simplification error you have to decide if you may neglect the influence of on quantity - or not.

Comment: Rin = R1||R2||r_pi (with CE across RE or without RE at all) The input resistance with RE and without CE capacitor is Rin = R1||R2||(r_pi + (beta+1)*RE)

Comment: @G36 But that last equation (r_pi + (beta+1)*RE) applies for CC output resistance, right?

Comment: No, CC output resistance = (r_pi/(beta+1))||RE if we ignore R1,R2

Comment: @Keno In general, you should never neglect r_pi resistance in your calculations. Maybe when you have a large RE resistance ( larger than 1k) without Ce capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are TWO high-pass filters in that circuit.

The input cap is one.

The emitter-resistor-bypass is the other.

Both of these capacitors cause a rising output signal level.

Thus 12 db/octave or 40dB/decade.

Its your job to manage the timeconstants of these TWO HPF.

---

What is the input impedance?

Zin is Z(c1) + the parallel combination of

a) R1

b) R2

c) Miller Capacitance [stage voltage gain * Cob (C collecter to base) ]

d) the sum of beta* [1/gm + { R4 in parallel with Z(20uF) } ], 
   where beta*1/gm is R_pi.

Comment: Ok. But that stil doesn't explain the meaning of r_pi, or when should it be neglected and when not.

Comment: Part d) of your answer is NOT correct. You forgot the effect of negative feedback,

Comment: @ LvW You are correct. 'd' should be beta * { 1/gm + (R4 in parallel with Z(20uF)}. Edited the answer. Thanks.